# Run query from FORM with variable

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I need to calculate weighted price index between 2 retailers (weighted on retailer 1 turnover). I need to calculate this index using different Item compositions (different top n).

Table1 contains data on area-week-item level.
[image: Table1]

The basic approach of weighting is:

> SUM(price1/price2 * turnover)/SUM(turnover)

I calculate it with the following Query statement:

```
 SELECT week, SUM(price1/price2 * turnover)/SUM(turnover) AS [PriceIndex]
 FROM Table1
 GROUP BY week;
```

According to the business needs I usually need to calculate this index with different set of products - only private label, only vegetables or - the most simple example - for only TOP n products (based on turnover in Q1'16).

I want to make a simple form in Access using VBA with several parameters for my query.

Form example
[image: Form example]

I have Dictionary tables with item-code descriptions (to select only beer category) and TOP 500 ranking table. I've made a query, that works - it JOINS top 500 table (it consists just code column with needed codes. I can manually write number of TOP codes (hilighted the string with ***).

```
SELECT week, SUM(price1/price2 * turnover)/SUM(turnover) AS [PriceIndex]
FROM Table1 AS F INNER JOIN TopTable AS T ON F.code=T.code
WHERE F.code IN (
***SELECT TOP 500 code
FROM TopTable)
GROUP BY week;
```

Now the main question. How to make the illustrated form?

I've made the beginning:

```vb
Private Sub Command_Click()

Dim top_num As Long
Dim SQL As String

top_num = Top_number.Value

sSQL = _
"SELECT week, SUM(price1/price2 * turnover)/SUM(turnover) AS [PriceIndex]" & _
"FROM Table1 AS F INNER JOIN TopTable AS T ON F.code=T.code" & _
"WHERE F.code IN ( " & _
"***SELECT TOP top_num code" & _
"FROM TopTable)" & _
"GROUP BY week;"

' ????

End Sub
```

I need just to execute SQL statement with form variable top_num.

Comment: your question is well detailed but I am still not sure to understand what you want.... you want to display the results of your query somewhere in the form ? Also what is the purpose of the combobox ? In your VBA code you seem to only use the entry from Top_number and you do nothing with the combobox

Comment: I want to get the results in standard access query output (like table view) for further export to excel or csv. Combo box is just for example, it's for the same purpose as Top_number, to add WHERE condition for items category(like beer or vegetables)

Comment: As far as I can tell, you cannot open a `SELECT` query in datasheet view if you define it with VBA and do not save it. Can you save the query first and simply have VBA open it with `DoCmd.OpenQuery`? Do you need assistance referencing form objects as criteria for a query?

Comment: @ChristopherD. that is not true there are multiple ways to do it...

Comment: @ThomasG Ok, so you need to use DAO, ADO? `DoCmd.RunSQL`, `CurrentDB.Execute `, and `DoCmd.OpenQuery` won't work without an action or saved query, which seemed to be where he was heading. Could you give us a hint?

Comment: @ChristopherD. there's not need `docmd` or whatever. Access is built for this, you just assign a SQL query to a form's control source like  have shown in my answer... This is the most simple way to do that but there are many others like using a `querydef` from a passthrough query if the source tables are not in the current DB

Comment: @ThomasG Ah I thought he was asking for datasheet view instead of a subform. Haven't used `querydef`, I will try that out.

Comment: @ChristopherD., Yes, it will be great if i can just run my Query, but with variable from textbox in Form. (referencing form objects as criteria for a query)

Comment: You can reference form controls in query criteria using [Forms]![nameOfMyForm]![nameOfMyControl]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to display the results of you query in your form, you have to do it in a subform.

### create the Subform

1. create a new form, name it Subform1 or anything else you like.  click on the square which is top left of the form and bring the property window. Under "Format", "default display", select "Datasheet".
2. Your query returns 2 columns, so you need to add 2 textboxes on your form
3. You have to bound your textboxes to the column names returned by your query: select a textbox and bring the properties window, under "data" tab the first field is "control source", there you specify your query column names :  `week` for one textbox, `PriceIndex` for the other

Your Subform is ready, save and close it.

### Add the subform to the form

Open the main form in design mode and add a SubForm control to it. When you create the control the wizard ask you which will be the data source for it, select `SubForm1`

### Adapt the code

```
Private Sub Command_Click()

Dim top_num As Long
Dim SQL As String

top_num = Top_number.Value

sSQL = _
"SELECT week, SUM(price1/price2 * turnover)/SUM(turnover) AS [PriceIndex]" & _
"FROM Table1 AS F INNER JOIN TopTable AS T ON F.code=T.code" & _
"WHERE F.code IN ( " & _
"***SELECT TOP " & top_num & " code" & _
"FROM TopTable)" & _
"GROUP BY week;"

' Add This :
Me!subform1.Form.RecordSource = sSQL


End Sub
```

You're done

Comment: Thank you, but as i wrote in comments i want to see my output in datasheet view for futher export to exel..

Comment: @MiroslavAtanasov If you do what I explained, your results will appear in the subform in datasheet view.... that's exactly what you asked.

Comment: Yes, it's true! I thought that results in form means that i see only 1 row and need to navigate with arrors to see another. Thank you!